# Finding the accuracy of an HMM model for POS-Tagger

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, pos-tagger

I am implementing the `Viterbi Algorithm` for `POS-Tagger` using the `Brown-corpus` as my data set. Now an important aspect of this `NLP` task is finding the accuracy of the model. So I really need help as what to implement. It's easier using the `nltk toolkit` but since I am not using a toolkit, I am stuck on how to determine the accuracy of my model. Any help, code examples or referral links would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To calculate accuracy on any dataset, count the number of words (excluding start and stop symbols) that you tagged correctly, and divide by the total number of words (excluding start and stop symbols).